# React - Mobx - Fetch - DRY Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dry, mobx

I am trying to clean up some code to remove redundancy and have some questions around best practices.

To keep it simple lets say I have 3 mobx stores `PeopleStore`, `PlacesStore`, and `AuthStore`.

All of these stores connect to a 3rd party api using `fetch`.

The `AuthStore` provides login functionality and has a property: `@observable apiToken`

There is duplicate logic in the other stores, setting the api url, the token, etc...

I tried creating the following file:

```js
// ./api.js

const url = 'https://example.com'
const options = {
   headers: {
      Authorization: ??? (how do I access AuthStore.apiToken)
   }
}

export const api = (endpoint) => {
  fetch(url + endpoint, options)
}
```

Then in `PeopleStore`

```js
import api from './api'

class PeopleStore {
   getPeople() {
     api('/people');
   }
}
```

(This is just an example of the concept and not the actual code)

My quesions are:

- Is this a good approach or are there better ways to go about this?
- How do I access the `apiToken` inside `api.js`?
- Am I correct in assuming that `api` is just a function and not a react component?

  - If so, can I still `inject` the `AuthStore` into the `api()`? (I believe I ran into issues with this)
- My other thought would be to wrap all of the Stores in an `HOC` which provides this functionality, but again (I'm assuming) the Stores are not actual react components, does this cause any issues?

Comment: Take a look at this - it helped me a lot with how to organise mobx stores https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to just set your authorization header globally at the top level of your app.  This would require you to install [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or something similar

For example, in your root index.js:

- Get your api key, via `process.env.apiToken` or however you are getting it
- Set the header:

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = apiToken;`

You can also set the base URL to help with the paths:

`axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';`

This way you do not need to worry about the token, it will just be taken care of.